# How to put 1.5*10**15 into json

Tags: python, json

I just need to know how to put in a numerical value such as 1.5x10^15 into json. I assumed the same syntax as python would work but json doesn't like the *s it seems.

Comment: You will have to include the literal result - JSON cannot contain expressions of any kind. Are you absolutely sure you mean JSON and know that it's a data transfer format?

Comment: You can write this as `1.5e15` in both Python and JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1.5x10^15` isn't a "numerical value," it's an **expression**. You could put that numerical value in JSON (`{"value":1500000000000000}`, or `{"value":1.5e15}` also works), but [JSON](http://json.org) has no syntax for expressions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the exponential notation in JSON. [RFC 7159 -- 6. Numbers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-6), says:

> A number is represented in base 10 using    decimal digits.  It
> contains an integer component that may be    prefixed with an optional
> minus sign, which may be followed by a    fraction part and/or an
> exponent part.

So you could use something as `1E400` in theory, although keep in mind that different implementation will have different limits.